# Type conversion error in method when creating new instance

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I am working only with integers and want to create a new instance of Fraction. I receive the error that I "Cannot implicitly convert type. 'Fractions.Fraction' to 'int'". The problem has to do with creating the new instance in this specific method. I need to return all three values from the method back to the class.

I have stepped through the code with the debugger and verified that the values are getting changed correctly. I am just unable to get them to return correctly. The error is on the last line of the reduce method. Still somewhat new to C# and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
public static int Reduce(int wholeNum, int numer, int denomi)
{
    int reduceWhole = (int)wholeNum;
    while(numer > denomi)
    {
        numer -= denomi;
        reduceWhole += 1;
    }
    while (denomi % numer == 0)
    {
        int factor =  (int)denomi/numer;
        numer = 1;
        denomi = factor;
    }
    return new Fraction(reduceWhole, numer, denomi);

}
```

Comment: change the return type to Fraction.

Comment: Test this with `Reduce(0, 20, 50)` and see if you get what you expect (or any fraction that doesn't reduce to `1/n`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then simply change the signature of the method to return `Fraction` instead of `int`:

```
public static Fraction Reduce(int wholeNum, int numer, int denomi)
{
    // ....
    return new Fraction(reduceWhole, numer, denomi);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was not aware that you could return with the class name.

Comment: @KABW: That's the type. It can be a primitive like `int` or a reference type like your custom `Fraction`. All types can be treated as(they inherit from) [`Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691139%28v=vs.71%29 Btw, you could also even return a collection of `Fraction`, for example as `List<Fraction>`, any type is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `Reduce` claims to return a value of type `int`, but your return line is returning a type of `Fraction`.  You need to change the first line of your code from `int` to `Fraction`:

```
public static Fraction Reduce(int wholeNum, int numer, int denomi)
{
    int reduceWhole = (int)wholeNum;
    while(numer > denomi)
    {
        numer -= denomi;
        reduceWhole += 1;
    }
    while (denomi % numer == 0)
    {
        int factor =  (int)denomi/numer;
        numer = 1;
        denomi = factor;
    }
    return new Fraction(reduceWhole, numer, denomi);

}
```